# How to get Chrome to STOP offering to remember password for one site?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

In searching this site for "Chrome password" I see lots of questions about how to get Chrome to remember a website password, but I have the opposite problem: I want Chrome to **STOP** asking if it should remember the password to a website.

Whenever I visit a particular website, Chrome asks if it should remember the password, no matter how many times I answer "Never".  How can I force Chrome to stop asking me this and just allow me to manually enter the password each time?

**I want Chrome to remember my passwords for other websites**.  I don't want to turn off the remember password function entirely, I just want it to stop asking me to remember the password for this particular site, which is what it should do when I click "Never".

Comment: It works for me, there must be something funny about that specific website. You don't need to answer that pop-up though; it will go away on its own.

Answer (score -2):

There is a setting to turn off this feature:

1. Open the settings
2. Click "Show advanced settings" at the bottom.
3. Find the section titled "Passwords and forms"
4. Uncheck "Offer to save your web passwords"

You can also just copy this to your address bar to skip steps 1-3: `chrome://settings/search#save%20password`

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I should have been more clear: I don't want to turn off the remember password feature entirely, I just want it to quit asking for one particular website, and I can't get Chrome to remember that.

Answer (score -2):

You can turn of this setting in the advanced settings in your google chrome browser, under the "Passwords and Forms" tab, uncheck the "Offer to save your web passwords" box

Example:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned in my question that I don't want Chrome to quit remembering all passwords, I just want it to quit offering to remember for one particular website when I click "Never".